# Use xsane as OCR without scanner

Tags: ocr, xsane

When I start xsane, It exits with the message no decvice accessible.

But I would like to use it just as OCR tool.

How can I suppress the device search?

Comment: Xsane isn't an OCR tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tesseract-ocr or cuneiform directly (command line) or with another frontend, try gscan2pdf, it can use a scanner, but you can load an image file, too.